# Why does Spark not run on Eclipse?

Tags: java, python-3.x, eclipse, hadoop, pyspark

I have installed pysark2.1 with hadoop2.6 on Eclipse (Eclipse plugins: PyDev) using Python 3.7, JRE 8, JDK 1.8.

I am trying to run a simple test code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

But I get the following error:

> Using Spark's default log4j profile:
>   org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties Setting default log level
>   to "WARN". To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For
>   SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel). 18/12/30 17:04:33 ERROR
>   SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread
>   Thread[main,5,main] java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found:
>   _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CALLBACK_HOST
>
> at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonGatewayServer.scala:50)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1228)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer$.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala:37)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\charfoush\eclipse-workspace\sample2\test2.py", line 7, in
>
> ```
> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\charfoush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py",
>   line 173, in getOrCreate
>
> ```
> sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\charfoush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py",
>   line 351, in getOrCreate
>
> ```
> SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\charfoush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py",
>   line 115, in **init**
>
> ```
> SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\charfoush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py",
>   line 300, in _ensure_initialized
>
> ```
> SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\charfoush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py",
>   line 93, in launch_gateway
>
> ```
> raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number") Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending
> ```
>
> its port number

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur for instance:

- either if you have a version mismatch
- or if you do not have defined properly `SPARK_HOME` AND `PYTHONPATH` environment variables (ensure none of them is targetting an older version)

Answer (score 0):

Working for me with `eclipse neon 3`
https://blog.puneethabm.com/pyspark-dev-set-up-eclipse-windows/[enter link description here](https://blog.puneethabm.com/pyspark-dev-set-up-eclipse-windows/)